# Warning : invalid props and should not use Route component and children in same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using BrowserRouter with App as parent component and UserInfo as child. Unable to fetch data I am getting errors as mentioned in question I am using BrowserRouter with App as parent component and UserInfo as child. Unable to fetch data I am getting errors as mentioned in question

//    This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

var UserInfo = require('./Components/UserInfo');

var routes = (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="user/:username" component={UserInfo} />
            </Switch>
        </Route>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

> //App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

var history = require('react-router').browserHistory;

class App extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  }
  constructor(props, context) {
     super(props, context);
  }
  submitUser(event) {
    console.log(this.refs.inputUser.value);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.context.router.history.push('/user/${this.refs.inputUser.value}');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="uk-navbar-container uk-margin" uk-navbar="true">
          <div className="uk-navbar-left">

            <a className="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="/">  Github search  &nbsp;
              <span uk-icon="icon: github; ratio: 2.2" className="uk-margin-large-right"></span>
            </a>

            <div className="uk-navbar-item  uk-navbar-right">
              <form onSubmit={this.submitUser}>
                <input className="uk-input uk-form-width-medium"
                  type="text" placeholder="Github UserName...." ref="inputUser" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary">Search &nbsp;
                <span uk-icon="search" className="uk-margin-small-right"></span>
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="uk-navbar-item  uk-navbar-right"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div className="uk-container-large">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

//UserInfo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

var $ = require('jquery');

class UserInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    getInitialState() {
        return {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.params.username !== this.props.params.username) {
            this.fetchData();
        }
    }

    fetchData() {
        $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/${this.props.params.username}')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((user) => {
                this.setState = { user: user }
            });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.user) {
            return (
                <div className="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match">Loading......</div>
            )
        }
        var user = this.state.user;

        return (
            <div className="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match" uk-grid>
                <Link to={`/user/${user.login}`}>
                    <div className="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
                        <div className="uk-width-auto">
                            <img className="uk-border-circle" width="60" height="60"
                                src={user.avatar_url} />>
                 </div>
                        <div className="uk-width-expand">
                            <h3 className="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom">
                                {user.login} ({user.name})
                            </h3>
                            <p className="uk-text-meta uk-margin-remove-top">
                                {user.bio}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserInfo;
```

Comment: which version of react router are you using ?

Comment: "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-class": "^3.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"

Comment: have you tried replacing the Switch ?

Comment: replace Switch with?

Comment: Just replace it ! No need to use it.

Comment: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`.
    in Route

Comment: Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in the UserInfo Component.

1. You have not set the Initial State of user in the constructor.
2. No need for another then in $.getJSON().You already getting the response , just setState the user with the response and you are good to go.

   ```
   class UserInfo extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
        this.state={
           user : "",
         }
   }    
   componentDidMount() {
       this.fetchData();
   }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if (prevProps.params.username !== this.props.params.username) {
           this.fetchData();
       }
   }

   fetchData() {
           $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users/subhanshu')
           .then((res) => {    
              this.setState({ user : res })
           },this);
   }

   render() {
       if (!this.state.user) {
           return (
               <div className="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match">Loading......</div>
           )
       }
       var user = this.state.user;

       return (
           <div className="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match" uk-grid>
               <Link to={`/user/${user.login}`}>
                   <div className="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
                       <div className="uk-width-auto">
                           <img className="uk-border-circle" width="60" height="60"
                               src={user.avatar_url} />>
                </div>
                       <div className="uk-width-expand">
                           <h3 className="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom">
                               {user.login} ({user.name})
                           </h3>
                           <p className="uk-text-meta uk-margin-remove-top">
                               {user.bio}
                           </p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </Link>
           </div>
       );
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<BrowserRouter>` should be like,

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and if App is not a generic parent and is used only to show `UserInfo`, inside the App component's render you can give,

```
<div className="uk-container-large">
   <Route path="user/:username" component={UserInfo} />
</div>
```